# Classifying double-pipe separated values in specific columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2016, I have a table with 4 columns. One of the column is formatted as JSON and contains double-pipe separated 4-character "codes" associated with two possible keys, `A` and `B`. I am only interested in the code associated with `A`.

| id | purchase_date | price | item_codes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-06-23 | 34.99 | `{"A": "CE01 || DF04"}` |
| 2 | 2022-06-24 | 149.99 | `{"A": "CE02 || DF01 || CE05"}` |
| 3 | 2022-06-26 | 9.99 |  |
| 4 | 2022-06-26 | 79.99 | `{"A": "CE04"}` |
| 5 | 2022-06-27 | 14.99 | `{"A": "DF01", "B": "XA01"}` |
| 6 | 2022-06-27 | 10.99 | `{"B": "XA01 || XA03"}` |
| 7 | 2022-06-29 | 119.99 | `{"A": "CE06 || DF02"}` |

I am looking to create a view to extend this table and display all `A` codes equal to `CE01`, `CE02`, `CE03` in a `purchase_code` column, all `A` codes equal to `CE04`, `CE05`, `CE06` in a `sales_code` column and all `A` codes equal to `DF01`, `DF02`, `DF03`, `DF04` in a `shipping_code` column. Note that only one code per column is possible, in other word, the data will never have two codes belonging to the same column as values for `A`. Also note that I have no control over the format/structure of the data in column `item_codes`.

| id | purchase_date | price | purchase_code | sales_code | shipping_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-06-23 | 34.99 | CE01 |  | DF04 |
| 2 | 2022-06-24 | 149.99 | CE02 | CE05 | DF01 |
| 3 | 2022-06-26 | 9.99 |  |  |  |
| 4 | 2022-06-26 | 79.99 |  | CE04 |  |
| 5 | 2022-06-27 | 14.99 |  |  | DF01 |
| 6 | 2022-06-27 | 10.99 |  |  |  |
| 7 | 2022-06-29 | 119.99 |  | CE06 | DF02 |

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(   id            int,
    purchase_date date, 
    price         money, 
    item_codes    nvarchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO @MyTable (id, purchase_date, price, item_codes)
VALUES
(1, '2022-06-23', 34.99, '{"A": "CE01 || DF04"}'),
(2, '2022-06-24', 149.99, '{"A": "CE02 || DF01 || CE05"}'),
(3, '2022-06-26', 9.99, NULL),
(4, '2022-06-26', 79.99, '{"A": "CE04"}'),
(5, '2022-06-27', 14.99, '{"A": "DF01", "B": "XA01"}'),
(6, '2022-06-27', 10.99, '{"B": "XA01 || XA03"}'),
(7, '2022-06-29', 119.99, '{"A": "CE06 || DF02"}')

SELECT 
    t.id, 
    t.purchase_date, 
    t.price, 
    ic.code
FROM 
    @MyTable t
OUTER APPLY 
    (SELECT 
         "A" as code
     FROM
         OPENJSON (t.item_codes)
         WITH ("A" varchar(255))) ic
```

What is the most efficient way to split and classify codes in column `item_codes`? I am able to split all values using a combination of `STRING_SPLIT` and `REPLACE` (since `STRING_SPLIT` only takes a single separator character), but struggling joining/classifying the results.

Comment: Storing json in relational databases often causes headaches. Storing proprietary data formats, such as delimeted strings, causes even more headaches. I strongly recommend an ETL layer to reformat the data before ingestion in to the database. Whatever you do, don't encapsulate the transformation in a view, it will perform horribly and be a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

- 1st `CROSS APPLY` is retrieving **A** value as [code] column from the JSON.
- 2nd `CROSS APPLY` is *tokenizing* the [code] column via XML.
- Finally. we are using XQuery and its FLWOR expression to break down
  (classify) XML tokens into the appropriate columns in the `SELECT` clause.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(   id                      INT PRIMARY KEY,
    purchase_date           date, 
    price                   money, 
    item_codes              nvarchar(max)
);

INSERT INTO @MyTable (id, purchase_date, price, item_codes)
VALUES
(1, '2022-06-23', 34.99, '{"A": "CE01 || DF04"}'),
(2, '2022-06-24', 149.99, '{"A": "CE02 || DF01 || CE05"}'),
(3, '2022-06-26', 9.99, NULL),
(4, '2022-06-26', 79.99, '{"A": "CE04"}'),
(5, '2022-06-27', 14.99, '{"A": "DF01", "B": "XA01"}'),
(6, '2022-06-27', 10.99, '{"B": "XA01 || XA03"}'),
(7, '2022-06-29', 119.99, '{"A": "CE06 || DF02"}');

DECLARE @separator CHAR(2) = '||';

SELECT id, purchase_date, price, t1.code
    , purchase_code = COALESCE(c.query('for $x in /root/r[text()=("CE01","CE02","CE03")]/text() return $x')
        .value('.','VARCHAR(10)'), '')
    , sales_code = COALESCE(c.query('for $x in /root/r[text()=("CE04","CE05","CE06")]/text() return $x')
        .value('.','VARCHAR(10)'), '')
    , shipping_code = COALESCE(c.query('for $x in /root/r[text()=("DF01","DF02","DF03","DF04")]/text() return $x')
        .value('.','VARCHAR(10)'), '')
FROM @MyTable
CROSS APPLY (SELECT JSON_VALUE(item_codes, '$.A')) AS t1(code)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(REPLACE(code, SPACE(1), ''), @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t2(c)
ORDER BY id;
```

**Output**

```
+----+---------------+--------+----------------------+---------------+------------+---------------+
| id | purchase_date | price  |         code         | purchase_code | sales_code | shipping_code |
+----+---------------+--------+----------------------+---------------+------------+---------------+
|  1 | 2022-06-23    |  34.99 | CE01 || DF04         | CE01          |            | DF04          |
|  2 | 2022-06-24    | 149.99 | CE02 || DF01 || CE05 | CE02          | CE05       | DF01          |
|  3 | 2022-06-26    |   9.99 | NULL                 |               |            |               |
|  4 | 2022-06-26    |  79.99 | CE04                 |               | CE04       |               |
|  5 | 2022-06-27    |  14.99 | DF01                 |               |            | DF01          |
|  6 | 2022-06-27    |  10.99 | NULL                 |               |            |               |
|  7 | 2022-06-29    | 119.99 | CE06 || DF02         |               | CE06       | DF02          |
+----+---------------+--------+----------------------+---------------+------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Brute force...

```
SELECT 
    t.id, 
    t.purchase_date, 
    t.price, 
    ic.code, 
    purchase_code.val AS purchase_code,
    sales_code.val    AS sales_code,
    shipping_code.val AS shipping_code
FROM 
    @MyTable t
OUTER APPLY 
(
    SELECT 
       CONCAT(' || ', A, ' || ')  as code
    FROM
        OPENJSON(t.item_codes)
            WITH (
                A   varchar(255)
            )
) ic
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT 'CE01' WHERE code LIKE '% || CE01 || %'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'CE02' WHERE code LIKE '% || CE02 || %'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'CE03' WHERE code LIKE '% || CE03 || %'
)
  AS purchase_code(val)
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT 'CE04' WHERE code LIKE '% || CE04 || %'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'CE05' WHERE code LIKE '% || CE05 || %'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'CE06' WHERE code LIKE '% || CE06 || %'
)
  AS sales_code(val)
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT 'DF01' WHERE code LIKE '% || DF01 || %'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'DF02' WHERE code LIKE '% || DF02 || %'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'DF03' WHERE code LIKE '% || DF03 || %'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'DF04' WHERE code LIKE '% || DF04 || %'
)
  AS shipping_code(val)
```

Slightly tidier...

```
SELECT 
    t.id, 
    t.purchase_date, 
    t.price, 
    ic.code,
    MAX(CASE WHEN code.value IN ('CE01', 'CE02', 'CE03'        ) THEN value END),
    MAX(CASE WHEN code.value IN ('CE04', 'CE05', 'CE06'        ) THEN value END),
    MAX(CASE WHEN code.value IN ('DF01', 'DF02', 'DF03', 'DF04') THEN value END)
FROM 
    @MyTable t
OUTER APPLY 
(
    SELECT 
       REPLACE(A, ' || ', ',')  as code
    FROM
        OPENJSON(t.item_codes)
            WITH (
                A   varchar(255)
            )
) ic
OUTER APPLY
  STRING_SPLIT(ic.code, ',') AS code
GROUP BY
  t.id, 
  t.purchase_date, 
  t.price, 
  ic.code
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=86b851dcc1e40bbe68ac3d507afa11c8